# Video streaming continues when page changes

Tags: php, html, video

I am working on a project in php and html, in that I have to put a video on the header of the website. 
And when I change the page the video should continue streaming, and also the link should be changed in address bar.
Does anyone have any idea how to implement that?

Comment: Set a cookie with the time played, then on page change forward the video to this time.

Comment: Only real practical way is to not actually reload the page. There are a few approaches to this, but really all of them boil down to either frames (or iframes) or ajax. Every time you use frames, God kills a kitten. Save kittens. Use ajax.

Comment: okay but i haven't worked anytime with cookies, If you dont mind than can you provide me the sample code?? @xyu

Comment: but with ajax the link should not be changed, the client wants to that the links should be changed and visible in address bar @DaveRandom

Comment: Take a look at the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and especially [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Comment: You can save time played using JS in window.name property. Value of this property doesnt change if you reload page or navigate through the website. It's a session cookie without using cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems you are facing. 1 is changing the address bar and 2 is continuing where the movie was.

Option 1:
When you change the addressbar, the page will be reloaded. The only exception to this is the bookmark (#code) which can change without page reload. You can use `document.location.hash` to change this. You could also check [jquery history plugin](http://www.google.be/search?q=jquery+history+plugin)  for a history plugin to the jquery platform to use ajax combined with this.

This allows you to use the back/forward buttons and sending url's to others. Keep in mind though that this does require some coding effort to make it work properly.

This does look better for a user, because the video will continue like nothing else changed.

Option 2:
Use the javascript `onunload` event to get the current position of the video which is playing. Then the page will reload to the new page just as it normally would and then use the `onload` event or jquery to move the video forward to the last playback position.

This looks less for a user because the video will stop, the page will refresh, the video will show stopped on start, the video will need to reload and then it can skip forward.

So in conclusion. Number one is the best way to go, but requires more effort then I can explain in a single awnser. Number two is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with php: I don't think its possible to do this only with PHP. You will need JS in order to load the content you need in your page via Ajax without refreshing the site. Without refreshing the site the video will continue playing and everything should be ok. Just use JS / Ajax to load the specific content needed.

Comment: ya I can do that, but I also need to change the links in the address bar. so how to do that?